# Does a parser have to consume all text input stream

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm building a parser generator,
currently it accepts a custom grammar and generates a C program to parse a text stream and generating a graphviz tree representation.

In my experiments definining sample grammar i found in some case the parse is terminated, but not all text input stream has been consumed.
With 'terminated' i mean, the main rule in the grammar has been evaluated true.

Should the grammar be modified to always have a parser to consume all source input text ?

Thank you

---

My use case is a single text file to be parsed completely.
Just a simple example grammar:

```
Main_rule: ID ID* ;

// ID is Terminal (a C variable token)

// Source text follows
var1 var2 123 var3
```

My C parser stops parsing before 123, (is not an ID) but evaluate true the main rule, and the text input stream is not completely parsed.

I can make some adjustment modifying the grammar (the language), if i add an arbitrary end token.
ie

```
main_rule: ID ID* END_TOKEN;
```

Is this the only way ?

Comment: If your parser is saying the text is valid, but there is still more text to consume because that text can affect the validity of the parse, then yes, something is not right.

Answer (score 1):

As usual with questions like this, the answer is "it depends on the use case."

Normally, parsers will consume an entire text, but it is not always clear what "an entire text" means. In some cases one parsed text stream is embedded inside another, and the termination is not an end-of-file (or end-of-string) marker.

In some cases, the extent of the embedded content can most conveniently be discovered by first extracting it, and then parsing the extracted string. However, this requires scanning the embedded string twice, and it is often the case that a more efficient solution exists. Also, in some cases there is really no way to discover the end of the embedded content without tokenizing it; consider, for example, parsing an embedded `$(`…`)` subshell inside a shell expression.

Parsing embedded languages is complicated, and elegant solutions are not commonly available. It is often easier to handle the complications with a traditional scanner/parser dichotomy, in which the embedding is dealt with entirely inside the scanner, possibly using a recursive call to another parser. In such a case, the parser itself does not directly deal with the input, and the scanner is responsible for producing an "end of input" token.

It is certainly the case that if there is unexpected text at the end of a fully-parsed prefix, that must be flagged as an error. Consequently, the parser, at a minimum, needs to be able to communicate to its caller whether it has consumed the entire input, and if not, exactly what remains to be consumed.

The existence of an explicit "end-of-input" token allows complete flexibility; if the grammar requires an "end-of-input" (with a production of the form `start': start END_OF_INPUT`), then of course the parsed text must terminate at the end of the input. The user is then free to define a grammar which does not require the entire input text to be parsed. But the flexibility comes at a price: in normal cases, the user is required to add the explicit augmented start production, and naïve users are likely to forget to do so. The difference between the two models is exemplified by [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/)/yacc (automatic augmented start production) vs. [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) (user must supply augmented start production if desired).